# How to access a variable present in a service

Tags: android, service

I want to access a variable present in a service from another service/an activity....

Can anyone give an idea?

Comment: Please be more specific or show some code.

Comment: Dear all Thanks for your inputs i'll try to implement with appropriate solution, as am new to android it'll take some time to check the feasibility. Here i want access one boolean variable from DeviceStorageMonitorService.java in ActivityManagerService.java,,

Answer (score 2):

To communicate between two service or activity, you need to use [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html)
It is not really difficult to do, and there is a lot of tutorial like [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/).

Comment: you don't _need_ to use aidl, you can simply bind to the service and send / receive messages to / from it

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `public` `getter` for that variable in your `Service` class, bind to that service, and access the getter to give you that variable.

Answer (score -1):

If what you mean is that you want to access the variable after you close and open the app, then you're probably looking for [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Note that this requires a context (an activity or service).

To store:

```
int data = 5;
SharedPreferences storage = getSharedPreferences("storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storage.edit();
editor.putInt("myInt", data);
editor.commit();
```

To get:

```
SharedPreferences storage = getSharedPreferences("storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int data = storage.getInt("myInt", 0);
```