# Pass String from activity to service?

Tags: android, arrays, service, android-activity

I am familiar with the method of passing arrays from one activity to another activity using putExtra and getExtra methods. However, whenever I try to get it from a service the following code doesn't work:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String Array = b.getStringArray("paths");
```

It is not recognizing the following:

```
this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

in the activity class I have the following:

```
    toService = new Intent();
    toService.setClass(this, Service.class);
    toService.putExtra("paths",Array);
```

in the service class:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        Paths = extras.getStringArray("paths");
        Toast.makeText(protectionService.this, Paths[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Nothing is appearing since Paths is not being assigned apparently.

```
Paths = extras.getStringArray("paths");
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Does it crash, gives wrong result, etc

Comment: I mean the service class doesn't recognize the code 

this.getIntent()...

Answer (score 1):

Where are you trying to access getIntent?

Here is a snippet from a program I have written which uses the getExtras:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // Do what you want 
      }
}
```

However, onStart is now deprecated so you should really use [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).
You get the intent as one of the parameters.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  handleCommand(intent);
  // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
  // stopped, so return sticky.
  return START_STICKY;
}
```

Otherwise you could use [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html), Preferences or any other example answered here: [How to access a variable present in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119517/how-to-access-a-variable-present-in-a-service)

Same question has already been answered [Android: how to get the intent received by a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964969/android-how-to-get-the-intent-received-by-a-service)

Edit: 
If you use this

```
toService = new Intent();
toService.setClass(this, Service.class);
toService.putExtra("array",Array);
```

You need to get the extras with the same key, here the key is "array"

```
Paths = extras.getStringArray("array");
```

Comment: I have edited the first post. So basically if extras is not equal to null then I can use extras.getStringArray("array") as it is used in an activity?

Comment: Yes, you dont need any getIntent() since you get the intent as one of the parameters in onStartCommand. So in the onStartCommand you only need to use intent.getExtras(). You should check that they are not null

Comment: I have added another part of my code in the original post, please check it out. Paths = extras.getStringArray("paths"); is not working.

Comment: Which API level are you using? I edited my answer, you need to have the same key when you put the extras and get the extras.

Comment: It's level 10. I do have the same key. it's "paths" on both sides.